# Непонятная ситуация со шрифтом woff2 (и он не работает у меня)

Tags: веб-программирование, шрифты

Есть у меня один и тот же шрифт в двух файлах - woff и woff2. Подключаю их так:

```css
@font-face {
   font-family: 'gico';
   font-weight: 400;
   src: local('gico'),
      url('../res/gico.woff2') format('woff2'),
      url('../res/gico.woff') format('woff');
}
```

Символы из woff отображаются без проблем, а из woff2 нет, вместо них какие-то квадратные рамки. В инструментах разработчика браузера заметил такую странную картину:

woff:
Response Headers
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 2644
**Content-Type: application/font-woff**
Date: Thu, 13 Feb 2020 05:11:10 GMT
ETag: "5e44d09e-a54"
Last-Modified: Thu, 13 Feb 2020 04:29:18 GMT
Server: nginx/1.10.3

woff2:
Response Headers
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Encoding: gzip
**Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8**
Date: Thu, 13 Feb 2020 05:11:10 GMT
Server: nginx/1.10.3
Transfer-Encoding: chunked

Не силен в особенностях работы шрифтов в браузерах. Мне нужно, чтобы woff2 заработал. В какую сторону копать?

Comment: Настроить веб-сервер

Comment: Ах, точно! Сервер вообще вылетел из головы! На что угодно уже подумал, но только не на это) Спасибо!